# Width is not set to 100%

Tags: css, position, width

Width is not set to 100%, what I did wrong, don't know.

```css
.av1 {
  float: right;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
}
.av {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .7857em 1.3em 0 0;
}
.u8 {
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 1.5em 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0
}
.si6 {
  background-position:-150px 0px;
  width:24px;height:24px
}
```

```html
 <span class="av1">
    <span class="av si6">
    <span class="u8">
    <form><input type="text"></form>
    </span></span>
</span>
```

width of .u8 could not set to 100% (page size) and could not float left ? Anybody help

Update: I have one problem now, therefore I update the code. The new si6 (Search Icon) is a css image sprite class which has own width and height (Not 100%) so, width of u8 class could not be set to 100%, any solution

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is inside `.av1` that limits the width. Give `width` to `.av1` and `.av` too.

```css
.av1 {
  float: right;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.av {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .7857em 1.3em 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.u8 {
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 1.5em 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
 <span class="av1">
    <span class="av">
    <span class="u8">
    <form><input type="text"></form>
    </span></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting width to 100% makes the element 100% of its parent element's width. So you'll need to set a width for each containing element.

```css
.av1 {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
}
.av {
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .7857em 1.3em 0 0;
}
.u8 {
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 1.5em 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<span class="av1">
    <span class="av">
    <span class="u8">
    <form><input type="text"></form>
    </span></span>
</span>
```

Or you can set the element's position to absolute and remove the parent's position to remove it from the parent's context:

```css
.av1 {
  float: right;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.av {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .7857em 1.3em 0 0;
}
.u8 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 1.5em 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  display:block;
  left: 0;
  top:0
}
```

```html
<span class="av1">
    <span class="av">
    <span class="u8">
    <form><input type="text"></form>
    </span></span>
</span>
```